# TypeError: _this2 is undefined REACTJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scope

To quickly explain my problem, in my render, I call a function that displays each element of my array via the map function.
When I click on the button, I want to send the element to another function. But when I click on the button I have the following error: "TypeError: _this2 is undefined", here are some screenshots of my code:

[image: My code]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The function you're applying with the map is creating a new this context that is inaccessible. I bet if you change it to an arrow function or .bind it to it's current this context, it would fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function calls in JavaScript create their own this context by default. If you apply a traditional function to a map, it creates a unique this context for each iteration when the function is called. To prevent, you can either explicitly tell the function the this context to bind itself to, or you can use arrow functions, which automatically applies the current this context to the context created.

I've created an example below to illustrate the problem. In the List component, you can see that  there is a renderList function that calls a map to iteratively render the items in the list. The below code won't work, as the map function creates a context in which the renderItem function is not defined:

```
class List extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  renderList(list) {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          list.map(function(item) {
            return <div>{this.renderItem(item)}</div>
          })
        }
      </div>
    )
  }

  renderItem(item) {
    return <div style={{color: 'green'}}>{item}</div>
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      {
        this.renderList(['one', 'two', 'three'])
      }
    </div>
  }
}
```

To fix this, either bind it to the current context:

```
renderList(list) {
  return (
    <div>
      {
        list.map(function(item) {
          return <div>{this.renderItem(item)}</div>
        }.bind(this))
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

OR implicitly bind the current this context arrow functions:

```
renderList(list) {
  return (
    <div>
      {
        list.map(item => {
          return <div>{this.renderItem(item)}</div>
        })
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: The first solution did not work in my case (the error being that this is not defined).

But the second solution you proposed works perfectly, thank you!